# onclick not working when onclientclick is used

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

**Design:**

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="RadBtnSubmit" Text="Submit" runat="server" 
            BackColor="#3399FF" ForeColor="White" 
            Height="30px" Width="100px" ButtonType="LinkButton" AutoPostBack="false"
            OnClientClick="return validate();" 
            UseSubmitBehavior="false" 
            OnClick="RadBtnSubmit_Click"/>
```

**javascript:**

```
    <telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock2" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function validate() {
            var CompanyName = /^[A-Za-z0-9]{3,20}$/;
            var txtCompanyName = document.getElementById('<%=radtxtCompanyName.ClientID %>').value;
            if (!CompanyName.test(txtCompanyName)) {
                document.getElementById("<%=radtxtCompanyName.ClientID %>").style.borderColor = "red";
                 alert("false");
                return false;
            }
            alert("true");
            return true;
        }
    </script>
    </telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

**This button is present inside an update panel.**
On Client Click alone is working and i am getting alerts correctly according to the condition.
But my onclick part is alone not getting executed.
I also tried putting return false along with function name in onclientclick that also did not work.
Thanks in advance Friends.

Answer (score 0):

set

```
OnClientClick="if(!validate()) return;"
```

If you set

```
OnClientClick="return validate() ;"
```

It always return no matter your validation is passed or not, and the post-back never triggered.

Comment: you should set AutoPostBack="true"

Comment: Make sure you pass the validation. Add OnClientClick="if(!validate()) return; alert('passed');".

Comment: Is the alert("passed") shown? if validation() return false then it never show up, also your postback never triggered

Comment: it means you didn't pass the validate function. Try to comment your code in validation() and return true in your validation. Also Set AutoPostBack="true".

Answer (score 0):

remove `AutoPostback="false"` and `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` from your aspx page. It will work for you.